# Nested RecyclerView with CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

My question is just like the question asked here : [Scroll behavior in nested RecyclerView with horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525314/scroll-behavior-in-nested-recyclerview-with-horizontal-scroll)

Similar to the Google Play store UI, I have a nested RecyclerView(Horizontal) inside a parent RecyclerView(Vertical scroll). The parent RecyclerView is a child of **CoordinatorLayout** in which the toolbar expands and collapse whenever the parent RecyclerView is being scrolled.

Everything works fine when we touch outside of the child RecyclerView (Check image 1 below) and scroll up then the CollapsingToolbar gets collapsed but **when i touch one of the the child RecyclerView and scroll up** then the collapsing of CollapsingToolbar doesn't happens.

[The below image shows when we touch between Featured and Trending and scroll-up]
[image]

[The below image shows when we touch **on Featured list** and scroll-up]
[image]

**UPDATE :**

activity of CoordinatorLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/coord_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activity.ChannelHubOld">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:background="@color/pkDarkGrey"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/sidebar_header"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ActionBarWidget"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!-- Parent RecyclerView --->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_pagelayout"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Had the same issue.
Fixed by setting [setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean)) on the horizontal nested RecyclerViews. It seems like the nested scroll wasn't intercepted properly by the `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` when not setting this. Try it out!

---

NOTE: you also have to add a layout behavior (example: `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` ) to the inner (nested) RecyclerView for this to work

Comment: yea.. i already solved it! i need to apply layoutBehavior in xml for NestedRecycler and then setNestedScrollingEnabled to false.

Comment: @fast3r You are my hero. This has to be an accepted answer - works just right.

Comment: I have to add that setting it in xml doesn't work for API 19 (and presumably API 17). Set it in code instead for it to really work.

Comment: @squeeish It's supported in XML only from API 21 and above.

Comment: Works for me even without "app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"" on the inner recyclerview. I do have that line in the outer view, though.

Comment: thank you very much. I was struggling with this for months: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56509759/bottomsheet-issue-with-nested-scrolling-recyclerview-nestedscrollview. Disabling **nestedscrolling** on all my horizontal recyclerviews worked !

Answer (score 0):

Check [Creating Collapsing effect](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout). this might help you.

code from link if link gets broken.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: add for layout manager like this LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        // use a linear layout manager
        myUpdatedProductsListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering how to solve the same problem but with inner horizontal `ViewPager2`, here is the solution:

`(viewpager.getChildAt(0) as? RecyclerView)?.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false`.

If you're wondering why `getChildAt(0)`, well `ViewPager2` is a ViewGroup which contains `RecyclerView` as its child. So setting `isNestedScrollingEnabled = false` straight to `ViewPager2` - will not work since we need to target `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score -5):

I have a solution for you and I tried this recently so it should work.

Inside your recyclerview, put in your nestedScrollView instead of the other way around like [Scroll behavior in nested RecyclerView with horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525314/scroll-behavior-in-nested-recyclerview-with-horizontal-scroll) suggested.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                >
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: hi @Simon Wont the app get crash?and answer in the link u have provided says RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView but ur answer is opposite to it.

Comment: tried now. App crashed. Throws :
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager

Comment: add for layout manager like this                                     LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                                                                          // use a linear layout manager myUpdatedProductsListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);