# Recyclerview not scrolling smoothly before scrolling finish

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling, recyclerview-layout

i am having problem with scrolling i mean the scrool fast but it's look like lagging before scrolling finish 
here i define RecyclerView :

```
RecyclerView recyclerView=fragment.getRecyclerView();
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(fragment.getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(fragment.getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
 ArrayList<InstaPostModel> rowListItems=getInstaPostListSample();
        InstaPostAdapter rcAdapter = new InstaPostAdapter(rowListItems);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
```

and here onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final InstaPostModel p = items.get(position);
    context = holder.itemView.getContext();
    Glide.with(context).load(R.mipmap.mee_small).into(holder.userPhoto);
    Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.post_image).into(holder.photo_content);
    Glide.with(context).load(R.mipmap.love_gray_icon).into(holder.bt_like);
    Glide.with(context).load(R.mipmap.comment_icon).into(holder.bt_comment);
    Glide.with(context).load(R.mipmap.share_icon).into(holder.bt_share);

    holder.userNameTextView.setText(p.getPosterUserName());
    holder.postContent.setText(p.getText());
    holder.post_date.setReferenceTime(p.getDate().getTime());
}
```

and here RecyclerView.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/qatar_now_posts_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        tools:context=".uis.fragments.home.QatarNowFragment"
        />
```

**Edit**
also i have bottom navigation bar in same fragment and it show when scrolling

**Edit 2** here is video [link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/hn7w8xsbu3ke8xq/mobizen_20180708_203934.mp4/file) showing the lag
i tried all the solution but no one help me.
i have added all my code
please any help?

Comment: what is parent layout of fragment? if it is scrollbar then refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525314/scroll-behavior-in-nested-recyclerview-with-horizontal-scroll

Comment: i have just recyclerview element

Comment: @MohammadSommakia Are the images so much big in terms of size?

Comment: no it's about 50  kb

Comment: In every item of your recyclerview, you are loading those same images. Then why you are not setting those images in the layout file?

Comment: I'd try the following. (a) Remove those lines that are loading the drawables through Glide, instead of that add the drawables directly as `src` in your ImageViews (b) Remove the `DividerItemDecoration` line from the Adapter intialization. See if that works and maybe you can spot the problem.

Comment: it' hardcoded example @Avijit Karmakar

Comment: not working  @4gus71n

Comment: Okay, that's weird, the code looks pretty straight forward. Try to set the visibility of the ImageViews to gone, to check if the problem is coming that way. The adapter initialization is being made in the onCreateView or onViewCreated hook methods from the fragment? Can you add a video of the lagging that you're talking about? Did you try to deploy the App in another emulator/device?

Comment: thanks for helping @4gus71n i have edited the question with link to show the lag in the video

Comment: any solution @4gus71n please?

Comment: try in a different phone

Comment: i tried it in samsung A5  and Huawei and another phone but same result

Comment: It looks okay. I think it's a different code problem.

Comment: you see the video ?... like what ?

Comment: @MohammadSommakia I'm scrapping the bottom of the barrel here. The only thing that I can think that could be messing with the Recycler is (a) Show us how are you loading the data, are you sending some sort of http request? In which thread is that request running? (b) Try to get rid of the images, download some really small image from google and try with that, if performance improves then there's the issue (c) Did you override any other type of hook method in the adapter implementation? (d) Can you post the InstaPostModel class?

Comment: no i am testing the app by hard code only if it worked then i will implement real data with real request. ok i will show you all the code in the adapter

Comment: Why you need to load resources using glide when there is `src` tag in `xml`?

Comment: will.. i fix it but still lagging

Comment: in android profiler i have about 25 mb graphics  and about 40 mb java

Comment: What did you fix?

Comment: sorry i mean i put the resources in xml not in glide but no changes

Comment: The chances are you had wrap-content ImageViews. You need to set fixed dimensions or at least one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not see any problem with your code. Still below points need to be considered.

(1) What could happen that size of **image** you are getting from API is **too large**. Check size of API and make it reduce by 200 kb max. (100-150 kb will be enough too).

(2) You **should not disable cache** as it will improve user experience by storing image in cache and load next time by cache not by URL.

(3) You **don't need to use `material-ripple`** library for a simple ripple effect available in Android now. Add this attribute to your `ImageView`

```
 android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

(4) Check how many items you are loading at once. You should not load many items at once. See [Architecture component paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/)

(5) Also check size of your resources like `love_gray_icon`. I think it should be max **70*70**. If you have larger than that, you should resize it. [**Resize multiple images at once**](https://www.iloveimg.com/resize-image). Also compress images before use, that will decrease image size up-to 80%. After resize, [**compress images**](https://www.iloveimg.com/compress-image).

(6) Glide is an well maintained library so `onViewRecycled` is redundant.

Finally bit amendment in your code.

```
  private void loadImage(ImageView iv, String url) {
        Glide.with(iv.getContext()).load(url).thumbnail(0.5f).into(iv);
    }

    private void loadImage(ImageView iv, int resId) {
        Glide.with(iv.getContext()).load(resId).thumbnail(0.5f).into(iv);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final InstaPostModel p = items.get(position);

        loadImage(holder.userPhoto, Urls.BASE_URI + p.getUserPhotoUrl());
        loadImage(holder.photo_content, Urls.BASE_URI + p.getPostPhotoUrl());
        loadImage(holder.bt_like, R.mipmap.love_gray_icon);
        loadImage(holder.bt_comment, R.mipmap.comment_icon);
        loadImage(holder.bt_share, R.mipmap.share_icon);

        holder.userNameTextView.setText(p.getPosterUserName());
        holder.postContent.setText(p.getText());
        holder.post_date.setReferenceTime(p.getDate().getTime());
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

It might be because of the images are too big

You can resize it using glide like

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(imgUrl)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .error(placeholder)
    .placeholder(placeholder)
    .dontTransform()
    .override(200,200)
    .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have several improvement suggestions for you.

- You are loading too many images in a list item. Reduce the image loading as much as possible. For example, you might consider setting the default images for the like and share button which are not usually changing in your application. Set them as `android:src` in the list item layout.
- Check if the Instagram images are too big in size. You might get an API to load an average sized image.
- Use a selector instead of creating a nested view to have a ripple effect on clicking on your like or share button in the list item. Try to keep the list item layout as simple as possible and try to avoid nested view hierarchy as much as possible.
- Remove the `onViewRecycled` function from your adapter which I found unnecessary.
- Initialize the adapter with the `Context` passed to it in the constructor. You do not have to get it every time inside your `onBindViewHodler`.
- You do not have to initialize the `RequestOption` each time in your `onBindViewHolder` function. Just initialize once and use it in each Glide image loader.
- Remove the button, comment and share image loaders and supply the images there as the source from the layout as stated before.
- Use `DiskCacheStrategy.ALL` to cache your images so that it does not load each time you open the application or load the `RecyclerView`.

Hence, the final adapter should look like this.

```
public class InstaPostAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InstaPostAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<InstaPostModel> items = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;

    // Initialize the context once, use it everywhere
    public InstaPostAdapter(List<InstaPostModel> items, Context context) {
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public InstaPostAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.insta_post_list_item, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final InstaPostModel p = items.get(position);
        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(Urls.BASE_URI + items.get(position).getUserPhotoUrl()).thumbnail(0.5f)
                .apply(requestOptions)
                .into(holder.userPhoto);
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(Urls.BASE_URI + items.get(position).getPostPhotoUrl()).thumbnail(0.5f)
                .apply(requestOptions)
                .into(holder.photo_content);

        // Removed the like, comment, share images which should be set from layout.

        holder.userNameTextView.setText(p.getPosterUserName());
        holder.postContent.setText(p.getText());
        holder.post_date.setReferenceTime(p.getDate().getTime());
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void add(InstaPostModel post, int i) {
        items.add(post);
        notifyItemInserted(i);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public ImageView userPhoto;
        public TextView userNameTextView;
        public ImageView bt_more;
        public ImageView photo_content;
        public ImageView bt_like;
        public ImageView bt_comment;
        public ImageView bt_share;
        public TextView postContent;
        public RelativeTimeTextView post_date;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            userPhoto = v.findViewById(R.id.insta_user_photo);
            userNameTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.insta_user_name);
            bt_more = v.findViewById(R.id.insta_bt_more);
            photo_content = v.findViewById(R.id.insta_photo_content);
            bt_like = v.findViewById(R.id.insta_bt_like);
            bt_comment = v.findViewById(R.id.insta_bt_comment);
            bt_share = v.findViewById(R.id.insta_bt_share);
            postContent = v.findViewById(R.id.insta_post_content);
            post_date = v.findViewById(R.id.insta_post_date);
            setClickListener();
        }

        private void setClickListener() {
            bt_more.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, view);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
                    Snackbar.make(view, item.getTitle() + " Clicked", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                });
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_feed_popup);
                popupMenu.show();
            });
            bt_like.setOnClickListener(view -> Snackbar.make(view, "Like Clicked", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
            bt_comment.setOnClickListener(view -> Snackbar.make(view, "Comment Clicked", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
            bt_share.setOnClickListener(view -> Snackbar.make(view, "Share Clicked", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think the problem not from image  i think it's memory leak from java and graphics in android profillers it's 25 for java and 25 mb for graphics

Answer (score 1):

I think scrolling issue might be because you are reloading images while binding. You can use cache while loading photos and of course, Pagination.

Comment: If you are having number of images that you need to load.You can load like 10 at a time, when end of list hits, then load next chunk of images.

Comment: in my example there is about 5 post just and i saw the memory about 100 mb i don't know how to reduce it

Comment: Try caching once. Check memory in profiler, if problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize your code as,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final InstaPostModel p = items.get(position);
    context = holder.itemView.getContext();
   setImage(holder.userPhoto, p.getUserPhotoUrl());
   setImage(holder.photo_content, p.getPostPhotoUrl());
   setImage(holder.bt_like, R.mipmap.love_gray_icon);

        holder.userNameTextView.setText(p.getPosterUserName());
        holder.postContent.setText(p.getText());
        holder.post_date.setReferenceTime(p.getDate().getTime());

}

private void setImage(ImageView iv, String url)
{
          Glide.with(context)
            .load(Urls.BASE_URI +url).thumbnail(0.5f)
            .apply(new RequestOptions()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .skipMemoryCache(true).dontAnimate()
            )
            .into(iv);
}
private void setImage(ImageView iv, int resource)
{
          Glide.with(context)
            .load(resource).thumbnail(0.5f)
            .apply(new RequestOptions()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .skipMemoryCache(true).dontAnimate()
            )
            .into(iv);
}
```

It will surely decrease load while rendering.Make sure you use variable only when traversing in adapter because list.get(position) calls everytime is costlier for memory.

Comment: You have just made method in his code, this will not improve performance, because it is same as his code. It will make difference if you initialize Glide once in Constructor.

Comment: Yeah..That will reuse the same instance of Glide.

Comment: Your code will not reuse Glide instance, it will initialize again & again because you have put that in method.

Comment: so how to initialize glide once in constructure then use it @Khemraj ?

Comment: @MohammadSommakia This will not make measurable difference. Glide is an well maintained library. But you still have many things to consider, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody mentioned that you should use pagingadapter. I was using it but the scroll is not smooth. In my case I have placed the recyclerview inside a scrollable view. That was loading the whole rv despite using the pagingadapter. To make it simple: don't put rv in a scrollable view. If you need some header place it inside the rv with different item types.

Answer (score 0):

if items in recyclerview is same size ,you can try : 
recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);

Comment: try : set image frome drawable don't need glide.

Comment: setHasFixedSize is about the RecyclerView, not the items it contains. If your RecyclerView is going to stay the same height, you should set it to true.